# Questions regarding Cloudstack

Tags: apache-cloudstack

Need help on 3 aspects of Cloudstack. It has become the major point of our decision to go ahead with the implementation

**Serial port debugging:**

We do lot of serial port kernel debugging in Windows and UNIX. There is no out of box support for it . We need to go to VMWARE level to enable it  , and we want to shield users from this.  Any suggestions on this front.

**Memory Snapshoting**

People here are used for VMWare memory snapshoting feature.  Also the ease with which Workstation/vSphere manages the Snapshots. Is there any way we can use that in Cloudstack? Our implementation is on VMWare , so we already have things in place , so just want to know , how to get it integrated with Cloudstack.

**VMWare Tools**

Whenever we create an instance from ISO's , we see that Mouse do not work. It is really painful to install the VMWare tools and get the mouse working. Is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Need immediate feedback on Apache CloudStack?

Send your question to the [mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)

Need specific features to be added?

Talk to support Vendor such as [Citrix](http://www.citrix.co.uk/products/cloudplatform/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Serial port debugging: -- What Steps you follow in enabling it in vmware

Memory Snapshoting: -- Cloudstack provides the snapshot feature ,but after taking snapshot you can not create vm from that snapshot,first you will have to convert that snapshot in templates and then you can create vm

VMWare Tools -- You can use attach iso facility of cloudstack .Initially install operating system with tabs but after installation attach vmware-tools.iso to that vm from cloudstack and install it on browser itself.